# Stripping a pdf file from videos

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, multimedia

I have a huge pdf file (152M) containing embedded videos. I reckon most of its size must come from the videos themselves. I want to make a lighter version out of it so that it's easier to share and send around, so I would like to remove the videos.

Is there a simple way to do it? In particular, using free tools? Possibly a one-off solution without needing to remove the files one by one?

I thought of using imagemagick for it, but I can't find how and I'm not even sure it's possible

Comment: Search Google!  For example, https://pdf.wondershare.com/top-pdf-software/free-redaction-software.html and https://www.lifewire.com/best-free-pdf-editors-4147622

Comment: See also https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/best-free-online-pdf-editor-software/

Comment: Thanks for the resources @fmw42 . Well, of course searching Google is the first thing I did, I wouldn't be asking here if I had found it there. On the face of it, I don't see anything specifically related to my need in the links you joined, I guess I will try to delve into the webpages and the videos

Answer (score 0):

Well, I could not find a way to do it. However, my original problem involved a pdf exported from a `pptx` presentation, so I managed to remove the videos from the presentation.

This does not answer the question, but I had opened a parallel question on `askubuntu.com`, I'll put the link here if anybody is interested: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453755/stripping-a-pptx-presentation-from-videos-in-libreoffice-impress/